# 'Internal Server Error' when deploying Application with Traefik and LetsEncrypt

Tags: docker, ssl, https, lets-encrypt, traefik

I'm new to SSL certificates with Traefik and have been having real trouble getting a successful deployment.

I have a server and domain that I have deployed my application on using Traefik and Http without issue.  I would now like to deploy the same application, running on port 9000, to be deployed in Https using LetsEncrypt following the Traefik [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt/) .  I can verify that the certificate has been properly created using an SSL checker, however, when I try to visit the site I get `Internal Server Error`.  There are no errors reported in either of the docker logs and I cannot figure out what to try next.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik

  app:
    image: myapp_image
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:myapp.com"
      - "traefik.basic.port=9000"
      - "traefik.basic.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.admin.frontend.rule=Host:myapp.com"
      - "traefik.admin.protocol=https"
      - "traefik.admin.port=9000"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

traefik.toml

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "myapp.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "myemail@email.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to find a workable solution for this. I may have just been using old information but the best reference to host an application with Traefik on Https using LetsEncrypt was found [here](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/).

The working Yaml example is below.  Using this example will also eliminate the need for a Toml file!

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=postmaster@example.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```